# why sweetalert cannot show if onclick clicked

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

i want to delete the row. but when i click the button onclick sweet alert cannot show. and this my code:
load sweetalert in header:

```
<!-- Sweetalert -->
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/vendors/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

html view:

```
 <td>
                         <!-- <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/hapus_user/<?php echo $row->NIK ?>" id="btnhapusmarker" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" 
                         onclick="return confirm('Hapus User ?')"" role="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Hapus</a> -->
                         <a  onclick="hapususer()" id="btnhapusmarker" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button">
                          <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Hapus</a>
                       </td>
```

javascript code:

```
<script>
    function hapususer() {
      swal('sukses');
    }
</script>
```

Can help me?

Thanks,

Best Regrads.

Comment: `onclick="return confirm('Hapus User ?')""` <-- double quote.

Comment: if use ```onclick="return confirm('Hapus User ?')""``` its work. but i want custom the confirmation delete with sweetalert. i try just show sweetalert but canot work